# How to cancel iCloud Storage Subscription without IOS, OSX or Windows device?

Tags: icloud, storage, downgrade

I've switched to Linux recently due to my work specifics, now I want to downgrade to free iCloud storage plan, but the [related apple support page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201318) only describes how to manage iCloud subscription using OSX, iOS and Windows PC.

Is there any other way to cancel iCloud subscription without those devices?

Comment: I've already tried to click "downgrading" link in the email receipt, but that link points to the icloud help page which does not give any useful information to the related topic.

Comment: Also www.icloud.com does not provide any tools to manage your storage plan.

Comment: I hoped I can remove my credit card info at "Apple ID" management page, but it cannot be removed.

Comment: I would just drop a support request at Apple. Because I think it is not possible to do it yourself without one of the devices..

Comment: I don't like the idea to talk with apple support nor any other support team, usually those guys are asking a lots of stupid questions and are not very useful for real life problems.. but, I may be wrong, so this may be an option before I'll try to install Windows on Virtualbox ;-)

Comment: https://discussions.apple.com/message/31111221 - here I was told that managing iCloud storage is only possible by one of the supported devices, which is pity...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can borrow a computer or iOS device, you can use that to sign into iCloud and then change to settings that way. This is probably the only way to do it yourself without calling Apple directly and seeing if they will do it for you.

Apple devices will have iCloud software already installed, but for Windows machines, you would need to download the iCloud software and install it - https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT204283

Other than installing a VM running Windows, there is no iCloud software for Linux.

Comment: This is the final thing I'm going to do, but I'll rather install Windows on Virtualbox for this purpose. I also wish to remove my apple ID at all, but didn't found any similar option on their site... and I don't really like the idea to contact their support and listening/answering to various stupid questions ;-)

Comment: I'm accepting your answer as it seems like the only clean solution accordingly to the answer at (https://discussions.apple.com/message/31111221).